# Telerik Searchable radcombobox not repopulating after item is selected

Tags: c#, javascript, html, telerik, radcombobox

I have a RadComboBox that allows for custom searching for about 1500 records.  Once one is selected the User control changes accordingly.  If I were to want to select a new record, the selected record is the only record that displays and when you type in the search field, nothing is found either.

However, if you select a record, do what you need then click the drop down then click off it then click on it again, it resets itself as desired.  How can I make it so the drop down list populates itself on the initial click?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are losing the datasource.

On the SelectedIndexChange event, you can repopulate the datasoure and set currently selected value from arguments that are passed to this event.

So in a pseudocode it would look like:

```
procedure OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedValue = e.Value;
  (sender as RadComboBox).DataSource = YourMethodToGetDatasource();
  (sender as RadComboBox).DataBind();
  (sender as RadComboBox).SelectedValue = selectedValue;
}
```

and yes i know currently pseudo code doesn't look so pretty but of course you will need to use the id of your control in place of (sender as RadComboBox).

If someone know a better method for this i would be glad to gain this knowledge :)